# I can't convert a column on my csv dataset to datetime format even though I used the correct code

Tags: python

I loaded my dataset using csv.read, then ran the code

```
data["Time"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Time"], format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data
```

I then tried to seperate the time column to hours and days using

```
data ["date"] = data["Time"].dt.hour
data
```

But I'm gettin the error message below

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I checked the datatype and it's showing that the time column is still in object format. Please how do I convert it to datetime format? I'm working with an ipynb file

Comment: try it  `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], errors='coerce')`  ,if you set param errors='coerce' then if the conversion fails for any particular string then those rows are set to NaT

Comment: Can you show how is your dataframe looks like.